Same content displayed on multiple pages
I'm working on a React Native project using Expo Router, and I've encountered an issue where the same content from my notifications.tsx page is appearing on multiple other pages like accountPrivacy.tsx, security.tsx, and appPermissions.tsx.
Each page should have its own unique content, but instead, I'm seeing the Notifications page content across all these pages. Below is the relevant code:
_layout.tsx
import { Stack } from "expo-router";

export default function Layout() {
    return (
        <Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="userSettings" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="notifications" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="accountPrivacy" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="security" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="dataManagement" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="appPermissions" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        </Stack>
    );
}

notifications.tsx
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { router } from "expo-router";
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";

export default function notifications() {
    const settingsPage = () => {
        router.push("/settings/userSettings");
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.navigationBar}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={settingsPage} style={styles.backButton}>
                    <Ionicons name="chevron-back" size={30} color="#fff" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <Text>Hello from Notifications.</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        marginTop: 20
    },
    backButton: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 15,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: '100%',
    },
    navigationBar: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 60,
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginBottom: 10,
    }
});

accountPrivacy.tsx, security.tsx, dataManagement.tsx, appPermissions.tsx:
Each of these files is structured similarly to notifications.tsx but should have its own content. However, the content from notifications.tsx is showing up instead.
I've checked my layout configuration, and everything seems correct. What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure each page displays the correct content?

It might be you are not using component in Stack.Screen.
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import Settings from "../pages/settings";

export default function Layout() {
    return (
        <Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="userSettings" component={Settings} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        </Stack>
    );
}


expo-router doesn't have a component option with Stack.Screen

There maybe some issue with you folder structure where you have placed all your pages components.
But you can probably resolve this by dynamically importing the screens as shown below:
<Stack.Screen
 name="notifications"
 options={{ headerShown: false }}
 component={() => require('./pages/notifications').default}
 />

<Stack.Screen
 name="accountPrivacy"
 options={{ headerShown: false }}
 component={() => require('./pages/accountPrivacy').default}
 />


expo-router doesn't have a component option with Stack.Screen
